# How to redirect from one url to another url in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using an Apache/2.2.15 as the web server  currently, I am facing an issue in apache layer regarding the redirect functionality.

my requirement is to redirect  from https://hostname/mysoftware or 
https://hostname/mysoftware/ to https://hostname/mysoftware/index

For  the same, I added  the following entries in the apache configuration file  tried using both Redirect  and RedirectMatch is not working as expected

it keeps on appending index page to URL

Redirect permanent /mysoftware  https://hostname/mysoftware/index

RedirectMatch permanent /mysoftware  https://hostname/mysoftware/index

RedirectMatch permanent /mysoftware/ https://hostname/mysoftware/index

RedirectMatch permanent /mysoftware/  https://hostname/mysoftware/index

Getting error  like

- - [19/Jul/2018:07:30:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 252
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:15 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/ HTTP/1.1" 301 252
- [19/Jul/2018:09:22:16 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/index HTTP/1.1" 301 257
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:16 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 262
  - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:16 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 267
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:17 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 272
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:17 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 277
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:17 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 282
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:18 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 287
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:18 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 292
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:19 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 297
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:19 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 302
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:19 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 307
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:20 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 312
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:20 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 317
- - [19/Jul/2018:09:22:21 +0000] "GET /mysoftware/indexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindexindex HTTP/1.1" 301 322

So can anyone  guide  what mistake I am making here and how to rectify the issue

Comment: Redirect/ RedirectMatch only work on a path _prefix_, and append the rest to the target URL automatically. You should really use mod_rewrite here, rather than the Redirect directives.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it is working

RedirectMatch permanent ^/mysoftware/?$ https://hostname/mysoftware/index

let me know if there any better way to do this?